# Clarification on Server Actions in NextJS v13.4+

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, next.js13

Are server actions in NextJS the functional equivalent of a RPC into the backend?

One of the touted benefits of Server Actions is that it can work even without Javascript.  If it’s not run with Javascript, then what does run it?  Also, functionally, what are the benefits to this beyond being able to run when users disable javascript in their browser.

What are the security considerations here?  How (broad strokes) is security handled?  Is there something that makes sure only the client application of the app, can reach into the Server Actions of that app?  Can another app or via curl or something like that reach into Server Actions?

Many thanks.